# Explain lambda expression with new class instance

Tags: c#, lambda, interface, delegates, botframework

In [**Echo bot with state example**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-dialogs#echo-bot-with-state-example) `Post([FromBody] Activity activity)` method calls `Func<IDialog<object>>` type delegate:

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EchoDialog());
```

where `EchoDialog` has `protected int count = 1;` member which counts each call to `Task StartAsync()`. Correct wor only possible if `new EchoDialog()` executes only once so lambda deals with same object every call of `await Conversation.SendAsync()`. So lambda created only once and remains the same for each `Post([FromBody] Activity activity)` call, right? How lambda works here? Thanks in advance!

Have not find right answer in Troelsen book, :) Stackoverflow, MS docs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new `EchoDialog` will be created each time the delegate is executed, which will be an implementation detail of `SendAsync`.  Basically, you're passing a method definition to `SendAsync` and it will call that method one or more times.  Each time it calls delegate, the code on the right side of the `=>` will be executed.

If you want to ensure the *same* instance of `EchoDialog` is returned for all calls, you could do this:

```
var myDialog = new EchoDialog();

await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => myDialog);
```

This will return the `myDialog` instance every time instead of creating a new instance each time.

### Update

According to [the documentation of `Conversation.SendAsyc`](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d9/de8/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs_1_1_conversation.html#a00a038f65a58138efb9a500665d3bbeb), the delegate (which is referred to as the parameter `MakeRoot` ) is only called for new conversations and that the `EchoDialog` object is serialized and stored for future calls on that conversation.

> The MakeRoot factory method is invoked for new conversations only, because existing conversations have the dialog stack and state serialized in the IMessageActivity data.

Comment: I thought same too. Explain me then: how `this.count++` works in EchoDialog? It is not static.

Comment: I would have to see the code for `Conversation.SendAsync` to answer that. Do you have that available?

Comment: Yes, link in the question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-dialogs#echo-bot-with-state-example, create basic Bot project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart

Comment: I updated my answer with more details.  The documentation for `Conversation.SendAsync` states that the delegate is only called for new conversations and then is serialized and stored for reuse for the remainder of that conversation.

Comment: I see :) Read documentation carefully. Key point is the serialization!